# Access denied on wmi query to root\MicrosoftIISV2 with Administrator

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, wmi, get-wmiobject

I'm doing a wmi query to check whether a IIS pool is running.
Via powershell, the query works

```
Get-WmiObject `
    -Credential (Get-Credential) `
    -ComputerName MyMachine `
    -Namespace root\MicrosoftIISV2 `
    -Query "select * from IISApplicationPoolSetting where Name='W3SVC/APPPOLLS/MyPool'"
```

Via C#, I get a `ManagementException` with the ErrorCode `AccessDenied`

```
var ms = new ManagementScope($@"\\{myMachine}\root\MicrosoftIISV2", new ConnectionOptions
{
    Username = $".\\Administrator",
    SecurePassword = Secure("adminPwd")
});
var query = "SELECT * FROM IISApplicationPoolSetting where name='W3SVC/APPPOLLS/MyPool'";
using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(ms, new SelectQuery(query)))
{
    var objects = searcher.Get(); // throws here
}
```

The user in both cases is the machine Administrator account. I'm hoping this won't be necessary by setting the correct permissions.

I'm also checking the status of windows services by doing a query to the `root\cimv2` namespace and the `Win32_Service` class and it works perfectly in both aproaches.

Before I could get any approach working, I had to disable remote UAC.

```
Set-ItemProperty `
    -Path HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System `
    -Name LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy -Value 1 -Type DWORD
```

My questions are related to permissions/privileges:

1. Why do I get the AccessDenied Exception with the Administrator user? How can I debug this?
2. Is disabling the remote UAC strictly necessary?
3. Is using the Administrator account or an user in the Administrators group unavoidable?

Comment: You need to do:  ms.Connect(); before passing it into the ManagementObjectSearcher - so ideally just before your var query line.  You've told it what credentials to use, but forgot to attempt to connect as that user.  Disabling UAC shouldn't be necessary - and you should avoid doing that if possible.  Lastly, this depends on the user the calling machine is logged in as.  If the app is logged in as Domain/Administrator (not local Admin) - then "Administrator" will be able to call the remote PC and passing the credentials shouldn't be required.

Comment: Of course any other user with permission to access both machines should also work, but this will be a network AD security permission thing.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementscope(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Scott, 
1. calling ms.Connect() has no effect on the Exception. Furthermore it works without it on the root\cimv2 namespace.
2. It's true that the machine administrator does not need remote UAC disabled, but other local users in the administrators group do need it
3. I already noticed it's a security permission thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got a part of it.

```
new ConnectionOptions
{
    Username = ".\\localAdministrator",
    SecurePassword = Secure("localAdminPwd"),
    Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy
}
```

With the PacketPrivacy option, there is no exception no more, and I can use a local administrator (just a user in the Administrators group).

I'm not sure what this option does and why it's needed but it solved my main problem. If anyone understands this well enough to explain I still can mark the answer as accepted.

I'll keep exploring about the permissions to find out exactly what permissions are needed.